# Cant create Specflow file in Framework 4.6.1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, specflow

I have played around with SpecFlow for a week now, of course it works locally but when im using it in a project, I cant create any files.

[image]

We are using Framework 4.6.1

My dependencies looks like this.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "dotnet-test-xunit": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Selenium.Support": "3.0.1",
    "Selenium.WebDriver": "3.0.1",
    "Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver": "2.26.0",
    "Selenium.WebDriver.Extensions": "3.0.1",
    "SpecFlow": "2.1.0",
    "SpecFlow.Assist.Dynamic": "1.2.0",
    "SpecRun.Runner": "1.5.2",
    "System.Data.SqlClient": "4.1.0",
    "System.Runtime": "4.0.20",
    "System.Runtime.InteropServices": "4.1.0",
    "System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime": "4.0.10",
    "System.Xml.XPath": "4.0.1",
    "xunit": "2.1.0",
    "xunit.core": "2.1.0",
    "xunit.runner.visualstudio": "2.1.0"
  },"testRunner": "xunit",
  "tools": {
    "SpecFlow.NetCore": "1.0.0-rc6"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "precompile": [ "dotnet SpecFlow.NetCore" ]
  },
```

I have imported a complete SpecFlow test, that is actually visible in Test Explorer. But it would be much smoother if it was possible from the pipe.

Any Ideas?
We are using VSTF

Comment: Are they not available if you search in the Online templates section?

Comment: @silkfire No, completely empty

Comment: Strange. I have them visible at the top of the list, right before the `Class` item. Can you try reinstall your SpecFlow VS extension?

Comment: @silkfire still same problem. Maybe I need to add something to the template folder. 
Works fine if i create a new project locally...

Comment: So it works if you Add Item to a newly created project but not to the project you've been working on?

Comment: @silkfire yes exactly, the project im working on is using .Net Core and Framework 4.6 something.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132798/discussion-between-silkfire-and-dymond).

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the SpecFlow extension for Visual Studio. This will give you syntax highlighting and project templates so you can add feature files.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TechTalkSpecFlowTeam.SpecFlowForVisualStudio

You will need to install an extension specific to your version of Visual Studio. You can choose other versions from here:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/publishers/TechTalkSpecFlowTeam